# Question on business connections and page rank?

Tags: seo, facebook, pagerank, backlinks, search-results

I just want to ask this question to get a yes no answer on something that I've been wondering on lately.

So regarding how there are countless numbers of sites now that use the no-follow; making it harder to get ranking for your page if your website information might be something useful and will get traffic but maybe isn't something that your business connections share content of; but I am trying to find out if the benefit to having a bunch of say "likes" to your facebook page, but all the connection to your website's content isn't passing any benefit to your main page.
So are you then competing with your own website in regards to SERPs to your facebook page and that of your home page.  Am I correct on this; that if you start having your facebook page doing real good as far as connections and likes (helping bump up your facebook PageRank) but if you have links on your page with certain optimized keywords, that there is no benefit to your website (other than people getting to your facebook page, and then more likely to click to your page).

Hope I explained it well what I am asking.  Just wanted to get a better picture of this to know what I want to focus on as far as how I'll be linking to my desired landing pages in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook page likes don't have anything to do with where the facebook page ranks let alone your website ranks. The facebook page is ranking well mostly because of the internal links and probably a few externals if any going to it. If you're suggesting that you main domain has mostly nofollow links you should continue looking for ways to get dofollow links since links is what will help you rank higher. Good quality contextual links are best and at the least on a page which is cached by Google.

Again connections and likes do nothing to promote your facebook page. I bet if you create a page with such unique content that there are no other sites on the web with those words it will rank with 1 like. Google calculates facebook page rankings the same as it does your main website. Using hundreds of signals from onpage to off page and who knows what else. But likes i'm sure are not part of their algorithm.

If both pages are ranking in the top ten that's great. You should be asking people who visit your main website to like you on facebook and link to your facebook page. I wouldn't though have any link building campaigns focus solely on my facebook page. You have much more control of your website and what you can do with it vs facebook. So get them to your website, get them to opt in to your mailing list and to like you on facebook so you can continue marketing to them once they've left your website.